# SQL query to remove duplicated postmeta from wordpress database

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have some duplicated rows on my Wordpress wp_postmeta table. Actually hundreds of cases where old postmeta data are listed 2 or 3 times... maybe from some data import process done in the past... So I need to remove unneeded duplicate rows from wp_postmeta table, leaving just the ones with higher meta_id number...  To exemplify what the wp_postmeta table looks like:

```
meta_id |   post_id   |  meta_key   |   meta_value
155153  |   177115    |  owner_img  |   https://www.example.com/a.jpg
176231  |   177115    |  owner_img  |   https://www.example.com/a.jpg
193983  |   177115    |  owner_img  |   https://www.example.com/a.jpg
```

Note that these are 3 metadata for the same post on wp_post table (as it has the same post_id)... so I just need to keep the latest metadata row, and delete all other instance where metadata is duplicated for each meta_key... how can I do that?

```
DELETE wp_postmeta.*
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_ID = wp_posts.ID
```

Answer (score 6):

I was able to figure it out after many research, in case anyone out there is looking for the answer...

```
DELETE t1 FROM wp_postmeta t1 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta t2  
WHERE  t1.meta_id < t2.meta_id 
AND  t1.meta_key = t2.meta_key 
AND t1.post_id=t2.post_id;
```

Comment: Your problem was the exact same as mine and this query worked perfectly. Thank you so much! I'm not sure how it happened to begin with..

Comment: is it not need to compare meta_value ?

Comment: For my use, I added to the end: `AND t1.meta_value=t2.meta_value`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the deletion by first filtering out the lower valued meta_id

```
DELETE wp_posts 
FROM   wp_posts 
JOIN   wp_posts x ON x.post_ID = wp_posts.post_ID 
AND    wp_posts.meta_id < x.meta_id
WHERE  x.post_id=wp_posts.post_id
AND    x.meta_key = wp_posts.meta_key
```

exercise:

```
create table wp_posts (meta_id integer,
                   post_id   integer,
                   meta_key  varchar(20),
                   meta_value varchar(200)
                   );

 insert into wp_posts values(155153  ,   177115    ,  'owner_img','https://www.example.com/a.jpg');
 insert into wp_posts values(176231  ,  177115    ,  'owner_img' , 'https://www.example.com/a.jpg');
 insert into wp_posts values(193983  ,  177115    ,  'owner_img' ,  'https://www.example.com/a.jpg');
commit;
```

-- SELECT TO CHECK/VERIFY

```
Select  distinct wp_posts.meta_id
FROM   wp_posts 
JOIN   wp_posts x ON x.post_ID = wp_posts.post_ID 
AND    wp_posts.meta_id < x.meta_id
WHERE  x.post_id=wp_posts.post_id
AND    x.meta_key = wp_posts.meta_key
```

OUTPUT

```
meta_id
155153
176231
```

Delete

```
Delete  wp_posts
FROM   wp_posts 
JOIN   wp_posts x ON x.post_ID = wp_posts.post_ID 
AND    wp_posts.meta_id < x.meta_id
WHERE  x.post_id=wp_posts.post_id
AND    x.meta_key = wp_posts.meta_key

;
commit;
Select * from wp_posts;
```

OUTPUT

```
meta_id post_id meta_key    meta_value
193983  177115  owner_img   https://www.example.com/a.jpg
```

Comment: thanks, but wouldn't that delete data from wp_posts? I'm trying to delete duplicated postmetas(like the example above) that are linked to unique wp_posts... or will this delete the postmetas?

Comment: It should not , to verify run substitute `Delete wp_posts`  with `Select wp_posts.*` if it returns the meta_ids `155153 , 176231  ` than only those will be deleted

Comment: that returned Unknown column 'x.post_id' in 'where clause'... the wp_posts table doesn't have a meta_id column... I've edited the text of what's I'm trying to accomplish, sorry maybe my initial text wasn't very clear

Comment: Not sure why your getting it, I ran the full answer and updated the steps for you to re produce.

Comment: wp_posts table does not contain meta_id column, key item is post_id... need to delete from wp_postmeta, not changing anything on wp_posts table...
so exercise would need to be...
```
create table wp_postmeta (meta_id integer,
                   post_id   integer,
                   meta_key  varchar(20),
                   meta_value varchar(200)
                   );